# How to get sender from the method showViewController:sender:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers, and the first which used the method `showViewController:sender:`. Now I want get the sender in the second view controller, what should I do? This is my code:

```
UIStoryboard *DownLine = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DownLineServer" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
KindDetailViewController *kind = [DownLine instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KindDetailViewController"];
[self showViewController:kind sender:@"test"];
```

In the second view controller how do I get the "test" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is pass some data to `KindDetailViewController`. This isn't what the `sender` argument is for. Instead it is ([from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/showViewController:sender:)):

> The object that made the request to show the view controller

The easiest way is to just set properties on `KindDetailViewController` for example:

```
@interface KindDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someInfo;
@end
```

Then when you want to show it...

```
UIStoryboard *DownLine = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DownLineServer" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
KindDetailViewController *kind = [DownLine instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KindDetailViewController"];
kind.someInfo = @"test";
[self showViewController:kind sender:self];
```

Comment: Glad to help, please remember to accept this if it has answered your question.